# Remove Specific HTML Component After Successful Response With JavaScript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, dom-events, submit

I have an image component where the user has the option to delete the component (basically the image). The deletion in the MySQL database is handled by PHP, and I use the JavaScript `fetch()` API on form submission so that no hard refresh happens on the page when this happens. All of this works OK.

**The Problem**

The issue I have is there will virtually always be multiple instances of the component in the form, so after the fetch happens I obviously only want to remove the specific component that is tied to its related delete button. To do this I understand I need to use the `remove()` method on the component/HTML.

Normally with events such as `click` I would use something like `e.target.closest('.element').querySelector('.child-element')` but the issue I have is I need to link the `remove()` method to the `e.submitter` event, because I only want to remove that specific component that is linked to its delete button, and I want to do this after getting a `200` response to show the deletion happened in the database.

In the javascript below, the specific button used on delete submission is referenced using `e.submitter`, but I guess I need to find a way of storing that as a variable that I can then use in the `if(response.status === 200) {}` line of code ?

**JavaScript**

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.upload-form-js'),
uploadDetailsComponent = document.querySelectorAll('.upload-details-component')

// URL details
const myURL = new URL(window.location.href),
pagePath = myURL.pathname

if (forms) {
    forms.forEach((form) => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            const formData = new FormData(this);
        
            if (e.submitter) {
                formData.set(e.submitter.name, e.submitter.value);
            }
        
            fetch(pagePath, {
                method: "post",
                body: formData
            })
                .then(function(response){
                return response.text(); // stops hard refresh of the page
            })
                .catch((e) => console.error(e));
        });

        if(response.status === 200) {

            // remove the specific component linked to the 'submit' event using the 'remove()' method

        }

    });
} // end of if (forms)
```

**HTML** There are multiple instances of the image component inside the form. In the HTML below I've just shown two instances

```
<section>
    <form class="upload-form-js" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div class="upload-details-component">
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="delete" title="delete" value="12" class="dl-button">Delete</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="image-id" value="12">
        </div>
        <div class="upload-details-component">
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img src="image.jpg" alt="image">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="delete" title="delete" value="13" class="dl-button">Delete</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="image-id" value="13">
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `closest()` method for finding the image componenet closest to the button returned by `e.submitter`.

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.upload-form-js'),
    uploadDetailsComponent = document.querySelectorAll('.upload-details-component')
    
    // URL details
    const myURL = new URL(window.location.href),
    pagePath = myURL.pathname
    
    if (forms) {
        forms.forEach((form) => {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // this stops hard refresh of the page
                
                const formData = new FormData(this);
            
                if (e.submitter) {
                    formData.set(e.submitter.name, e.submitter.value);
                }
            
                fetch(pagePath, {
                    method: "post",
                    body: formData
                })
                    .then(function(response){
                      // you already have the response at this point. 
                      // Give a callback if required.
                      if(response.status === 200) {
                        // remove the specific component linked to the 'submit' event using the 'remove()' method. 
                        // 'closest()' will go up the DOM hierarchy 
                        e.submitter.closest('.upload-details-component').remove()
                      }
                      return response.text(); 
                })
                    .catch((e) => console.error(e));
            });
        });
    } // end of if (forms)
```